Surface_mesh with Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2
Instead of Point_3 I want to use std::pair<Point_3, unsigned> to generate TIN. How to mix Surface_mesh, Projection_traits_xy_3, Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2 and Delaunay_triangulation_2
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Projection_traits_xy_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/boost/graph/copy_face_graph.h>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/point_generators_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2.h>
#include <map>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel            K;
typedef CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<K>                                PrjTrts;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned, PrjTrts> Vb2;
typedef K::Point_3                                                     Point3;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point3>                                     Mesh;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb2>                      T2ds;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<PrjTrts, T2ds>                  TIN;

int main () {
   std::map<Point3, unsigned>  cgalPts;
   insertSomePtsIn(cgalPts);
   TIN dsm(cgalPts.begin(),cgalPts.end());
   Mesh sm;
   CGAL::copy_face_graph(dsm, sm);
   return 0;
}


It gives the error:

In file included from /home/Necktwi/workspace/displaz/src/render/PointArray.cpp:28:
/usr/include/CGAL/boost/graph/copy_face_graph.h:342:46: error: no matching function for call to 'get'
  342 |                                              get(vertex_point, sm)),
      |                                              ^~~
/home/Necktwi/workspace/displaz/src/render/PointArray.cpp:1035:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'CGAL::copy_face_graph<CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<CGAL::Epick>, CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned int, CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<CGAL::Epick>>>>, CGAL::Surface_mesh<CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Epick>>, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<bool, CGAL::internal_np::all_default_t>, CGAL::Named_function_parameters<bool, CGAL::internal_np::all_default_t>>' requested here
 1035 |       CGAL::copy_face_graph(dsm, sm);
      |             ^
/usr/include/boost/property_map/property_map.hpp:129:19: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'const T *' against 'boost::vertex_point_t'
  129 |   inline const T& get(const T* pa, std::ptrdiff_t k) { return pa[k]; }
      |                   ^
/usr/include/boost/property_map/property_map.hpp:165:3: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'readable_property_map_archetype<K, V>' against 'boost::vertex_point_t'
  165 |   get(const readable_property_map_archetype<K,V>&, 
      |   ^
/usr/include/boost/property_map/property_map.hpp:302:3: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'put_get_helper<Reference, PropertyMap>' against 'boost::vertex_point_t'
  302 |   get(const put_get_helper<Reference, PropertyMap>& pa, const K& k)
      |   ^
/usr/include/CGAL/Dynamic_property_map.h:232:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'CGAL::dynamic_vertex_property_t<T>' against 'boost::vertex_point_t'
  232 | get(const CGAL::dynamic_vertex_property_t<T>&, const G&)
      | ^
/usr/include/CGAL/Dynamic_property_map.h:240:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'CGAL::dynamic_halfedge_property_t<T>' against 'boost::vertex_point_t'
  240 | get(const CGAL::dynamic_halfedge_property_t<T>&, const G&)
      | ^
/usr/include/CGAL/Dynamic_property_map.h:248:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'CGAL::dynamic_edge_property_t<T>' against 'boost::vertex_point_t'
  248 | get(const CGAL::dynamic_edge_property_t<T>&, const G&)
      | ^
/usr/include/CGAL/Dynamic_property_map.h:256:1: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'CGAL::dynamic_face_property_t<T>' against 'boost::vertex_point_t'
  256 | get(const CGAL::dynamic_face_property_t<T>&, const G&)



Try adding #include <CGAL/boost/graph/graph_traits_Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>.
